# Why libxmljs is not able to parse the data read by fs.readFile()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, xml-parsing

I want to use XPath to filter out some elements in XML file.
I'm using fs module of node.js to read a XML file and passing the data read to libxmjs's parseXml().

Versions of fs and libxmljs

```
$ npm list libxmljs
`-- libxmljs@0.19.5

$ npm list fs
`-- fs@0.0.1-security
```

My code

```
var libxmljs = require('libxmljs');
var fs = require('fs');
var xmlref = fs.readFile('<filePath>','utf8',filterXmlContents);

function filterXmlContents(err,xml){
    console.log('Input XML:'+xml);
    //This prints the xml read by fs. It contains NodeOfInterest as well.
    var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);
    var node = xmlDoc.get('//NodeOfInterest');
    //But here I get undefined.
    console.log(node);
    console.log(node.text());
}
```

I don't know why libxmljs is not able to parse the content read by fs?
I tried

```
xmlDoc.getChildNodes()
```

and I get

`[ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]`

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

P.S. In my code libxmljs's parseXmlFile is not working. 
I get `TypeError: libxmljs.parseXmlFile is not a function`

Comment: Use the nodejs builtin [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) module instead. Try running `npm un -D fs` to uninstall the version of `fs` that you're currently using (which I think is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs)). Once it has been uninstalled you're script will utilize the builtin `fs` module, i.e. you don't need to reinstall anything.

Comment: I have the same default npm fs module.